# BInance Data; Convert Timestamp to date

Tags: python, pandas, date

I'm trying to convert a column nanoseconds to date format. I thought, as I read before all over place, that timestamp from Binance came in millis but it seems it comes in ns, if it helps to others:

```
0      1.595948e+12
1      1.595952e+12
2      1.595956e+12
3      1.595959e+12
4      1.595963e+12
    
495    1.597730e+12
496    1.597734e+12
497    1.597738e+12
498    1.597741e+12
499    1.597745e+12
Name: time, Length: 500, dtype: float64
```

so I need to multiply over 1.000.000 to get the right date applying "pd.to_datetime(df['time'])" and I do, I print dataFrame and I get it but the code stops with two different errors depending on how I do perform the mult:

opt A
'''

## transform values from strings to floats and milliseconds to date

```
    for col in col_names:
        df[col] = df[col].astype(float)
        df['time'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x: x*1000000)#<<this one
        df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
        #print (df['time'])
```

'''
I get this error:

```
df['time'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x: x*1000000)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Timestamp' and 'int'
```

Opt B

'''

## transform values from strings to floats and milliseconds to date

```
    for col in col_names:
        df[col] = df[col].astype(float)
        df['time'] = df['time']*1000000 #<<<<<<<<<<<this one
        df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
        #print (df['time'])
```

'''

but it raised the following error:

raise TypeError(f"cannot perform {name} with this index type: {typ}")
TypeError: cannot perform **mul** with this index type: DatetimeArray

In both cases the rpint(df) seems right:

```
495   2020-08-17 15:00:00
496   2020-08-17 16:00:00
497   2020-08-17 17:00:00
498   2020-08-17 18:00:00
499   2020-08-17 19:00:00
Name: time, Length: 500, dtype: datetime64[ns]
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

I would appreciate any hint on this.

Whole code below, I marked with "#this" the two lines that if commented the code runs Ok but with date in the '70, but uncommented alternatively they raise the correct date but the code stops in an error (sorry if it is not the right way to expose things around here):

'''

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json

class TradingModel:
    def __init__(self, symbol):
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.df = self.getData()

    def getData(self):

        # define URL
        base = 'https://api.binance.com'
        endpoint = '/api/v1/klines'
        params = '?&symbol='+self.symbol+'&interval=1h'

        url = base + endpoint + params

        # download data
        data = requests.get(url)
        dictionary = json.loads(data.text)

        # put in dataframe and clean-up
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary)
        df = df.drop(range(6, 12), axis=1)

        # rename columns
        col_names = ['time', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']
        df.columns = col_names

        # transform values from strings to floats and millis to date
        for col in col_names:
            df[col] = df[col].astype(float)
            #df['time'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x: x*1000000) #this 
            df['time'] = df['time']*1000000 #this
            df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
            print (df['time'])
def Main():
    symbol = "LINKUSDT"
    model = TradingModel(symbol)
    model.getData()
   
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

'''

Comment: Thanks for the update.  However, my answer still stands: you claim that the date column looks right when you print it.  If so, then I fail to see where you have a problem.  Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.  SO far, you claim that the intermediate results *are* what you expect.

Comment: Hi prune, I have no problem uploading the code as I have it. I'm editing the question whith the whole code at thui end of it. thanks

Comment: Please post a MRE; posting your entire code base is not appropriate.

Comment: edited with MRE, thanks for the Tips for newbies.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you attempt a nonsensical operation.  Your printout clearly shows that the column holds dates.  Just what the heck is `03:00 17 Aug 2020` times a million?  That's why you get an error: a calendar date is compatible with adding and subtracting `timedelta` values, but multiplication by an `int` doesn't make sense.

Note that your data frame is already quite happy interpreting this as a `datetime`; however you ingested the data, converting a `timestamp` with precision in nanoseconds, is quite compatible with the target type, `datetime` with precision in milliseconds.  There is no further conversion needed.

Comment: Hi Prune,the original column, before the mentioned operation, holds floats (i'm editing the original question adressing that)